# facebook FBSDKGraphRequest request giving me different UUID every time

Tags: facebook, swift, uuid, fbsdk

I'm developing an app that uses Facebook contacts. I'm saving those contacts in a local CORE DATA DB to use them when there is no connectivity. Unfortunately I'm getting different UUID results when I access tangible friends id's. What am I doing wrong?

```
  let friendsRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: ["fields": "id,username, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"])
  let userDetailsRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"])
```

in my case my ID is a 15 digit number like `000000000000000` and in my contacts I get a very long UUID's 110 characters like `HJd6gJgJzM7ezMgmIF_XCuoT2vNS29lntSInUEVwUXmI-03kHJd6gJyemrZ46hgJyemrZIG9w-hWcOcEMOapbpm4g-JyemrZINcu0_BCgMOasf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `taggable_friends` endpoint is for tagging people *only*, you are not supposed to misuse it to work around the limitation that your app can only see a user’s friends that are users of your app as well. (So you won’t get that through the necessary review by Facebook anyway.)

It does not return ids, but tokens only – and those are short-lived. Again, because they are to be used for tagging only, and not for the purpose of gathering information about users.

Comment: Thank you very much. So let me get this straight I might be able to access the Facebook contacts if Facebook reviews the app? I thought they had closed that door.

Comment: That’s why I said you _won’t get_ this through review. `taggable_friends` is for tagging friends in Open Graph stories only – and you need to get your usage of it reviewed, which won’t happen if you are trying to abuse it for anything else. Your app only has access to the friends of a user that are using your app as well (and have granted `user_friends` permission too), and that is what you will have to make do with.